# Network Error when calling axios get request in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using React.js in windows and when I try to call axios.get, I get Network Error.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73450:14)
```

My code is like this:

```
  const fetchCoins=async()=>{
    setLoading(true);
    const {data}=await axios.get(CoinList(currency));
    setCoins(data);
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

Comment: Is the API you are using on localhost or other network?

Comment: can you show the code for CoinList(currency)?

Comment: @Takkie253 also please show the code from where this `currency` is coming from.